# In LWC when i want to authorize an org ,

Tags: lightning-web-components

In Visual Studio Code for LWC when i want to authorize an org ,it says successfully authorized ,you may close the browser. But not showing the exit code and keeps on running.

How to solve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you get the SFDX retrieve deploy, etc. command in VScode in your SFDX project?

Comment: that command(retrieve source in manifest from org) is there and its working ,as i can see it retrieved all the classes and triggers.But authorize an org is still going on and on.